# Bootstrap custom carousel tweak

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i came across this demo: http://www.bootply.com/94444. It is almost exactly what i have been looking for.

As you can see it takes now 3 slides in one view. I would like to have only 2 slides in one view.

Can anyone tell my how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See this example: http://www.bootply.com/124246

You need to modify a few things on the 3 slides example..

- change the CSS from 50% to 33%
- change the cols from `col-4` to `col-6` so that the cols are 50% wide
- modify the jquery to only append the next sibling to the active item (creating 2 slides in each the active frame)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to change the carousel bootstrap to do what you want

but I propose to use [this](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) plugin javascript, which I think is great, give us a look

can be customized to 100%, and is right for you

Comment: Indeed. Very nice plugin. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: great :) , if the answer helpful to you "accept the answer", and help so other users